# passing java string variable in clickhouse query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, clickhouse

for example

```java
  public void invoke(String value, SinkFunction.Context context) throws SQLException {
    statement_.execute("INSERT INTO test (column_1) VALUES '"+value"');
  }
```

how to rightly insert value?

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/ru/yandex/clickhouse/integration/BatchInsertsTest.java#L63

Comment: @Denny Crane the links seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have got the connection you do this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO test (column_1) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        
statement.setString(1, value);
statement.addBatch();
statement.executeBatch();
```